# Difference between string[,] and string[][]

Tags: c#

Hopefully this is not a duplicate as I did do a search and found nothing.

At first glance I thought they would behave similarly but no.  One is a 2 dimensional array of string and the other is an array of string arrays, i.e. what you get back from (List<string[]>)obj.ToArray().

I know how to return the jagged array type using (List<string[]>)obj.ToArray().

How can I return 2d array using a similar concept, i.e. build up a collection object from other data and call ToArray or other method that will return a 2d array.

Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between a 2d array of strings and an array of string arrays? I don't see one... at least not in utility.

Comment: [**Arrays (C# Programming Guide)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal `new[] { new string[1], new string[2] }`, that's possible with `string[][]` but not with `string[,]`.

Comment: classic case of diplopia

Comment: @hvd Ah, I see the difference now. I would never do that though... and I'd probably call you an idiot if you did :-&(

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Creating a jagged array when given a number of single dimensional arrays can be a useful operation; and it notably doesn't require copying the data the way a multidimensional array would.  You can also do the reverse; pull out an array and then expose it externally without needing to copy the elements.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Why not? You expect to be able to store strings of different lengths in a `string[]`, would you not? What's so different about arrays of different lengths? It doesn't always make sense, but when it does, there's no reason to avoid it.

Comment: @Servy actually that makes sense but I'm typically using `List<T>` in code like that.

Answer (score 8):

One is a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx), where the other is a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

There are some differences.  A multidimensional array will guarantee each row having the length.  With a jagged array, each "row" is an array, and those arrays can be varying sizes.

Another difference is in memory layout.  A multidimensional array is a single object, the array elements are guaranteed to be closer together in memory.  Since a jagged array, is an array of arrays, there is no guarantee that the each array will be allocated sequentially in memory, particularly in multi-threaded situations.

It is also good to note that the [.NET Framework Design Guidelines for Array Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2604h5s.aspx) suggests to use jagged arrays over multidimensional:

> √ CONSIDER using jagged arrays instead of multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Cool.  A downvote without an explanation why.

Comment: If you want your rows allocated sequentially in memory (ie, you are working with bitmaps / video buffer) then you will want a multidimensional array rather than a jagged array.

Answer (score 1):

jagged array is string[][]
2d array is string[,]

In other words with string[,] each row has the same number of elements. 
in string[][] each row may have a different number of elements.